# HTML <a> tag event order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic question regarding a tag in HTML.

Say that I've got some HTML like this

`<a href="www.example.com" onclick="doSomething()">Do some work</a>`

When a user clicks on an anchor link (Do some work) which event will trigger first?

I mean whether `doSomething()` or `href` goes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what will happen:

1. The event will fire
2. the page will redirect.

But don't take my word for it, go test it out for yourself. I even got it started for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDdZS/

this is the simple code I used

```
function doSomething(){
 alert("hello");      
}
```

I added the return false, mentioned in other answers so you can see it in action. I didn't know about that actually, so always good to learn something new.

Comment: You can also do `onclick="return doSomething();"` and use `return false;` in the function for a specific condition

Comment: I actually did that in the jsfiddle example, and return false; from the function didn't prevent the redirect. I'm not claiming knowledge of how to make that happen, I've never done it.

Comment: And here's what I meant - http://jsfiddle.net/WDdZS/5/ - notice how `return false;` is only for a specific condition. So if you take out the `'asdf'` parameter, click the "Run" button for the jsFiddle, and then click the link, it should redirect. But as long as the `'asdf'` parameter is there, because the condition is satisfied, the behavior is prevented

Comment: I see what you did there. Sorry I'm working on like 3 different things. That completely makes sense. THank you.

Answer (score 4):

`doSomething()` go first.. and if it returns `false` or is prevented, then the anchor link is not called.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript will execute first.